# Python bytes are missing after recv from UDP socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp

```
import socket
import sys
import datetime
import os

try:
    username = "root"
    password = "Apacheah64"
    db_name = "DB_GPS"
    table_name = "Tbl_GPS"
    host = ""
    port = 6903
    buf = 4096

except IndexError:

    sys.exit(1)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind((host, port))

while 1:
    data = s.recv(buf)
    if not data:
        print("Client has exited!")
        break
    else:
        print("\nReceived message '", data,"'")

# Close socket
s.close()
```

the bytes i m received should be 43 bytes, but what i received from client is

Received message ' b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00NR09G05164\x00' ' ?
only 15 bytes. why?

Below is Original Bytes 43 bytes

`00 00 00 01 00 06 ec 44 76 a6 21 c2 00 00 08 00
45 00 00 2b 08 43 00 00 34 11 81 2b cb 52 50 db
67 0d 7a 19 24 2d 1a f7 00 17 83 26 0f 00 00 00
4e 52 30 39 47 30 35 31 36 34 00`

Comment: are you responsible for the server side? could you show code responsible for sending? (btw UDP is connection-less, so your `if not data` block kind of doesn't make sense.)

Comment: actually if not data will not happen, the problem is i can't receive the full packet >"<

Comment: Why are you putting simple variable assignments in a `try` block?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe missing bytes are simply not displayed by the `print`? Check `len(data)` value.

You can't receive incomplete packet over UDP, it will deliver you full datagram or nothing at all.

Comment: checked Len(data) is 15 bytes only